# How can I build up the #:usage-help string dynamically in racket lang's (command-line ...) function?

Tags: racket

I am trying to build a git-style CLI application, eg `racket-app command command-params ...`. This is similar to what you can do with [thor](http://whatisthor.com)'s `sub-command` feature.

I have this code:

```
(define commands
  (hash
   "noop"   (list "Does nothing"
                  (lambda () (log-info "noop was called :)")))
   "render" (list "Prepares and renders the static HTML (hugo)"
                  render-proc)))

(define s1 (build-possible-commands-from-the-keys-of-commands))

(define command
  (command-line
   #:usage-help s1
   #:args (op) op))

(cond
 [(dict-has-key? commands command) ((second (dict-ref commands command)))]
 [else (log-error "Unknown command")])
```

It fails with `command-line: #:usage-help clause contains non-string`.

If I replace the reference to `s1` with an actual string (eg `"aoeu"`) then it works just fine. I would like to build up that string (`s1` in this example) dynamically, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that the usage-help must be a literal string and not one computed as the program runs, because this string should be available from the command-line *without* running the program. That is, `raco help` should be able to provide the help string without running the program.

You can sort of work around this; you need to provide the string at expansion time. Here's the most straightforward way:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax my-cmd
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ str) 
     (define command
       (command-line
        #:usage-help str
        #:args (op) op))]))

(my-cmd "aoeu")
```

In this example, it's clear that I've separated the "command" call from the literal string, but it may not be so useful to you.

So, here's the question: what's the use case? How are you trying to abstract over the string?

#### EDIT

After reading over your use case, it totally looks to me like you want to use `parse-command-line`, as Jon Zeppieri suggested on the racket mailing list. This allows you to specify a procedure to be called when argument parsing fails, and you can emit any string you like.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this example. But this is punching way above my weight-class if I'm honest. I'm hoping that macros or macro-like features won't be required. I added more of my code to my question to illustrate what problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I can suggest a solution, but I'm guessing you'll get the help you need on the mailing list. Let me know if you want me to show you how to abstract over this using a macro!

Comment: I'll appreciate your suggestion, the mailing list is cool as far as it goes, but it's not SO...

Answer (score 3):

The grammar for `command-line` says:

```
flag-clause = ...
              #:usage-help string ...
```

This means that the `command-line` will not accept general expressions after
`#:usage-help`.

I can't think of a good reason for that restriction though. I too would expect an expression to be accepted.

I suggest asking at the Racket mailing list - maybe someone has an explanation - or if not maybe someone will change the behaviour of `command-line`.

Comment: I think this help string must be available without running the program... see my answer below.